# ActivityNotFoundException when opening the browser

Tags: android, browser, android-intent

sometimes my app crashes when i try to open a browser within the app for adds, here is my code:

```
public void onBannerClick(final View view){  
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
intent.setData(Uri.parse(mBannerURL));  
startActivity(intent);
```

and this is the stacktrace i get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2179)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2535)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9130)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:618)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:123)
at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3850)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:659)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2174)
... 11 more
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://xxxxxxxxx.xx }
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1449)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1419)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2878)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2984)
at com.XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXX.MainActivity.onBannerClick(MainActivity.java:830)
... 14 more
```

can any1 please help?

Comment: you could add a `try...catch` block around `startActivity()` if you simply don't want your application to crash. Now as to why it is crashing that will take some more effort and possibly the actual URLs it is being sent to

Comment: adding a try catch block i a good idea, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check to see that you scheme is spelled correctly.  I found that simply using "HTTP:" instead of "http:" caused exactly this problem.  Note at the bottom of this page:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html

... that scheme matching in Android is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably either you are getting some sort of HTTP error (e.g., invalid URL and a `404` response) or the HTTP response is served under a MIME type that your device lacks an app for.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue after a lots of try I found the issue was with my URL.
I changed the URL to https, later its work